# How to Schedule Cosmos DB Data Processing With Azure Functions using SpringBoot Application

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Has anyone tried creating any Azure Function in Spring Boot which will get triggered based on timer and will have CosmosDB(Mongo) Input Binding to read through the db for updates.

Comment: Such question is off-topic here,what have you tried? Or met any issues?Please post it out.

Comment: i just wanted to get a function created which has a time trigger and has a db binding......hell lot of info on .net but very few on java over springboot app.....but luckily I figured it out.... now I can place my business logic in it....

Comment: Got your idea and thanks for your sharing about your solution,you could mark yourself to end this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily I found how to do it in SpringBoot App

@FunctionName("hello123")
    public void execute(@TimerTrigger(name = "timerInfo", schedule = "*/1 * * * * *") String timerInfo,
            @CosmosDBInput(name = "documents", databaseName = "db1", collectionName = "col1", connectionStringSetting = "dbStr") Optional documents,
            ExecutionContext context) {